# Microsoft Access 2003 menu bar is missing under toolbar customize

Tags: microsoft-access

Last time I was trying to hide the menu bars in my existing database.

I added code in my module which I found on the internet. But now when I start Access I can't find the menu bars where I can usually see the File, Edit etc.

I tried to restore the default, the menu bar can't be found under the customize toolbar. Any idea what happened? This is added from the website:

```
Dim i
For i = 1 To CommandBars.Count
CommandBars(i).Enabled = False
Next i
```

I tried it but it didn't solve the problem. confused:(

Answer (score 1):

From this Microsoft Support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833219):

**Reset the toolbars in Access 2003**

Important : If you reset the toolbars in Access 2003 to their original settings, you may lose the custom changes that are implemented in the toolbars.

1. Start Access 2003.
2. On the Tools menu, click Customize.
3. On the Toolbars tab, click to select the Menu Bar check box on the Customize dialog box.
4. Click Reset, and then click OK.
5. Click to select the Database check box, click Reset, and then click OK.
6. Click Close.

Comment: i tried this one already reset the toolbars, the problem is i don't see the Menu bar on the customize dialog box. Even after clicking on the reset button. this is really strange, already tried to restart my PC but still the menu bar is still missing. 
this is weird...

Comment: Might it not be a simpler solution to uninstall and reinstall Access?

Comment: i guess this is the last recourse I wanna do. thanks for the help.that's a lot of work again, it makes me not to like microsoft more.

Comment: Microsoft's relationship with the world is a love-and-hate affair.

Answer (score 1):

To restore all your menus you just need to change your code so it says 'true' instead of false

> *Dim i*
>
> *For i = 1 To CommandBars.Count*
>
> *CommandBars(i).Enabled =* ***True***
>
> *Next i*

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out! Right click at the top of the page by your toolbars, the Customize box appears. Click Properties...popup "Toolbar Properties" appears. At the top of that selected toolbar, select MENU BAR, and click restore defaults at the bottom. The menu bar should appear back at the top of your screen. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
commandbars("menu bar").Reset
commandbars("menu bar").Enabled = True
commandbars("menu bar").Visible = True
```